# How to send a newsletter?

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I am a newbie and this it is the first time that I have created an html and css code. 
I have written a newsletter and now I would like to send it but I do not have idea about how.
Right now the situation is as following:
I have a folder with an HTML file, a folder with the CSS file and another Folder with all the images.
Now I would like to send it, but as I said before I do not know how.
I have red that I need to make a unique file HTML and CSS (HTML with an in line CSS). Is that the only way to go?

Which program do you suggest to send the newsletter?
Where should I store the images in order to make them visible to the recipients?

Any suggestion???

Comment: Also, if you do choose a 3rd party website to send out your emails, you might want to check if they will host the images, otherwise you will probably need to purchase webhosting so you can host them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! do you any suggestion regarding the website?

Comment: I think MailChimp can host the images - http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-upload-an-image/  So you just need to upload them all to the gallery, and then replace the img src with the hosted version.

Comment: THanks again! you have been super kind!

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone above me, I would recommend Mailchimp too.

Now why it would be ideal in your situation is 'cos:

1. Since you've already created a separate html and css file, merging it into inline styles is going to take considerable effort if you have a lot of content. Mailchimp has a wide variety of templates to choose from where you can just pick a template which suits you and add just the content part.
2. Newsletters are very tricky to code since all email clients display content in a different way unless you're really proficient at writing newsletter html files from scratch. For eg, the email client Outlook (Microsoft) will ignore margins and some other css properties. The templates from Mailchimp have been perfected to show your content exactly like your design across almost all major email clients.
3. If you're going to send out a big number of newsletters, your newsletters might go into spam folders based on a variety of reasons. Mailchimp has authentication so that unless you go against some obvious law, your newsletter will land in your recipient's inbox.
4. You can also host your images on your own server and ask Mailchimp to reference that location. I do this when I send out newsletter for my website.
5. Its even got free plans to help start you out and see if it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have already inlined the css into the html...now I am trying to give @media attributes to maake it as much responsive as as possible..

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com) it is faster, easier and gives more options.

Comment: @Ygriko You can upload your own html. It also hosts your images.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools availbale which gives services for sending emails also many other features.

As your HTML mailer is ready with image folders. Try to use inline style and for the images use full path like `http://company.com/image/name.jpg` ofcourse you have to place this `HTML file` and `image folder` on the server as well. And then you have to copy all the HTML code and place in any marketing tool and then you ready to send emails.

1. [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/)
2. [Pardot](http://www.pardot.com/)
3. [Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp)

you can choose constant contact to sending email.they offer 30 days free trial.

Comment: I wouldn't put Pardot in the same group, as it is not an ESP. You could include other services like Campaign Monitor, MadMimi, or even transactional email services like Sendgrid, Mailjet or Mailchimp's Mandrill.

Comment: I worked  on Sugar, constant contact and now working on Pardot tool. As i mentioned other I found pardot a bit powerful tool where you can send a lots of campaign and you can make automation mail. you can track records of users. In addition you can make landing page, also its well integrated with Sugar CRM.

Comment: It does all of that, but it is more of an enterprise tool, designed to plug into a CRM. I'd consider it more of a competitor with Eloqua, Marketo, Exact Target (also owned by SF) and other Marketing Automation type tools, as email is just a small part of what it does. I guess he didn't mention any scope, I just wouldn't have grouped it with simple email sending tools like Mailchimp or Constant Contact.

Comment: well, you are also right. email services is just a small part they are providing. I don't have too idea about `mailchimp` so lets close this discussion.. see you.

Answer (score -1):

MailChimp is a good bet. Their API is wide enough to get into customising the hell out of their standard templates. Watch their pricing though, it can get out of hand the larger your cliental gets!

Comment: Thanks Harry, but I want to send the newsletter I have designed. But it seems that on mail chimp you can only insert an HTML file but not the CSS. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @user3441525 You need to inline all of your CSS, and then you should just be able to drop all the HTML into MailChimp and send.